# Default setting of ephemeral storage

Tags: kubernetes

What happens if I don't set ephemeral-storage limits in any of my pods? How does kubernetes sets the default limits?

I'm asking because I an error like this:
`the node was low on resource ephemeral storage xxxxKi which exceeds its request of 0`

What I don't understand is how the limit is being set if I don't set it?

(btw, I didn't set any namespace level limits)

Comment: Hi, which version of k8s are you using ? can you also check `kubect get quota`?

Comment: As I understand, if there is no boundary for the pod, It can consume as much as the node's disk/ storage capacity, which will create disk pressure, and kubelet will evict the pods

Comment: @refaelos Did you find a solution to this? If yes, can you please post the solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Macintosh1997 no I don't have an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `LimitRange` resource for defaults. Ref: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/09/19/local-storage-capacity-isolation-ga/

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: storage-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      ephemeral-storage: 10Gi
    defaultRequest:
      ephemeral-storage: 5Gi
    type: Container
```

Default is 0 which leads to NodeDiskPressure event when the pod uses all of the available disk space.